# Variable scope in PHP class

Tags: php

my problem is very straightforward but I can't resolve it.

In my index.php I'am including two PHP files.

```
    require_once("/lib/config.php");
    require_once("/lib/connect.php");
```

In config file I declare variable #config

```
$config = array(  
    "db" => array(  
        "www_db" => array(  
            "username" => "user1",  
            "password" => "pass1",  
            "conn_string" => "blabla"
        )  
    ),  
    "paths" => array("images" => $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/images")  
);
```

In connect.php I have a singleton class Connection.

```
    class Connection
    {

private static $instance = NULL;

public static function getInstance()
{
    if (!self::$instance)
        self::$instance = new Connection();
    return self::$instance;
}


private $conn;

// Create connection to Oracle
public function getConnection() 
{
    //if (INCLUDE_CHECK == true)
//  {
        $conn = oci_connect($this -> $config["db"]["www_db"]["username"], 
                            $this -> $config["db"]["www_db"]["password"], 
                            $this -> $config["db"]["www_db"]["conn_string"]);
```

My problem is that my Connection class doesn't see $config variable declared in config.php. I have also tried to declare $config as global. I am getting error " Undefined variable: config..." "... in connect.php".
Please help.

Comment: If you include a file with variables, you can't use $this because it refers to properties of the current object.

Answer (score 3):

You can't see the variable inside a class as it is declared outside. Pass it to the class,
use *Dependency Injection* ([either setter or constructor injection](http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/)) and then `$config` will be available in your connection class.

Comment: Hi Shaun, yes, that would work except the methods that need the DB info are all static (essentially alternate constructors) I could pass in the DB info as an arg to these, but in the interest of simplicity, I used the global keyword to pull them in from global scope. (See Chen's answer below).  Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `global` keyword to specify when you want to include global variables. 
For instance, this is how it works:

```
$config = array ('one' => 'two');

class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        print_r($config); // NULL
        global $config;
        print_r($config); // Array ( 'one' => 'ywo' )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chen! This is how I solved it because I'm using these inside static methods so the constructor injection and setter ways are not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding a new setter-method to your Connection.class, like:

```
public function set_config($config = array()) {
    if (empty($config)) return false;

    $this->_username = $config["username"];
    $this->_password = $config["password"];
    // ... 
}
```

Then you're able to use the data in other methods like:

```
oci_connection($this->_username, $this->_password);
```

Otherwise you set the $config global:

```
global $config;
```

Comment: @Havelock You're right, but I guess Exception-Handling is another chapter - I try to keep the example-code as simple as possible.  :-)

Comment: Like I wrote, I use statement global $config but still doesn't see $config variable.

Comment: did you try the setter-method?

Comment: @Igor Please post the solution, if it's possible. It could help anyone else who has the same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this:

```
private $username = "usr1";
private $password = "pass1";
private $conn_string = "connection_string";

private $conn;

// Create connection to Oracle
public function getConnection() 
{
    $conn = oci_connect($this -> username, 
                        $this -> password, 
                        $this -> conn_string);
    if (!$conn) {
       $m = oci_error();
       echo $m['message'], "\n";
       exit;
    }
    else
    {
        return $conn;
    }
}
```